# WooCommerce Composite Product Page has unwanted "QTY" input field above Add To Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, composite, product-quantity

Consider these two composite products, which were created to be identical in every way, except for the product name, sku, image, and options.

Even the composite options are more or less copies, the second one a copy from the first, except for the changes to the component names, prices, skus, etc.

The composite product on this link is correct, because immediately above the ADD TO CART button, there isn't a quantity select:

[26″ PATIO FR ON BLACK PEDESTAL](http://tecinfrared.com/product/26-patio-fr-freestanding-black-pedestal/)

The composite product on this link, on the other hand, has a quantity select input immediately above the ADD TO CART. I don't want it, and I want to remove it:

[26” PATIO](http://tecinfrared.com/product/patio-built-in-26-inch-fr/)

I have put the two product pages side-by-side, using the edit product page, compared the products at every level I can think of, comparing the component construction, the advanced tab of each component, and even comparing the components side-by-side (each component being a simple product), and I can't see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just in the settings of your product in Inventory options, enable "Sold individually :

[image]